# Can't insert foreign key value into linking table

Tags: php, mysql, foreign-keys, constraints

I am currently trying to insert data into a table called **"customer_quote"**, this table acts as a linking table between the **"customer"** table and the **"customer_tariffs"** table. It also records the user who sumbitted the data via the **"user"** table.

Here is a schema of my db:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/gyCdb.png
[image]

and here is a screenshot of the table that is not allowing me to insert into it.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/I7fsr.png

[image]

This is the process in how I insert into my db:

1. Insert data into **customer table**
2. Retrieve row id using mysql_insert_id
3. Insert data into **customer_quote** <--- Not working!

Here is the code:

```
    //code above this inserted data into customer table

//get id of row where data was just inserted
$sustomer->cid = mysql_insert_id($db);

//insert into customer_quote table
$database->query("INSERT INTO customer_quote (cid)
        Values ('$customer->cid')");
```

** New Error message**

> 'Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`quote_system`.`customer_quote`, CONSTRAINT `fk_customer_quote_customer` FOREIGN KEY (`cid`) REFERENCES `customer` (`id`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION)'

As you can see that error feedback is useless , so after about three hours of testing I have concluded that the problem is my "cid" column in the "customer quote" table.

It only accepts certain values however my own php variable has the correct value which is available to insert via phpmyadmin as you can see in the screenshot below.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/jMS15.png

[image]

So it has to be the constraints or something else in my table that is stopping me?

Any ideas how to solve this.

Thanks!

Comment: Loving the detailed post .... i just hope my answer is wrong ... because you could have saved all that effort by adding a `)` .....

Comment: 1. You don't appear to be using the cid variable you just got? But instead the customer->cid? I imagine these resolve in to the same thing? 2. I'm no PHP expert but shouldn't your code read: "INSERT INTO customer_quote (cid) Values ('$customer->cid')") - you're missing a bracket

Comment: sorry that was a type, i hand typed the code instead of pasting- oops!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I really hope its a simple typo in your question but your query isn't correct :

```
$database->query("INSERT INTO customer_quote (cid)
        Values ('$customer->cid'");
```

should be

```
$database->query("INSERT INTO customer_quote (cid)
        Values ('$customer->cid')"); // added closing bracket on values
```

Comment: Thanks, but now I get this error: -'Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`quote_system`.`customer_quote`, CONSTRAINT `fk_customer_quote_customer` FOREIGN KEY (`cid`) REFERENCES `customer` (`id`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION)' i

Comment: You cannot insert data into the table unless all of the constraints are met - your schema shows both `cid` and `uid` as being not nullable ... ie they are both required

Answer (score 2):

You have misplaced the double quote and missed a parens

Change the lines:

```
$database->query("INSERT INTO customer_quote (cid)
    Values ('$customer->cid'");
```

to

```
$database->query("INSERT INTO customer_quote (cid)
    Values ('$customer->cid')");
```

Comment: Thanks, but now I get this error: -'Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`quote_system`.`customer_quote`, CONSTRAINT `fk_customer_quote_customer` FOREIGN KEY (`cid`) REFERENCES `customer` (`id`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION)' i

Comment: @loosebruce: The value of `$customer->cid` doesn't exist in customer table.

Answer (score 2):

You have a missing ) at the end of your insert...

```
//insert into customer_quote table
$database->query("INSERT INTO customer_quote (cid) Values ('$customer->cid'");
```

should be

```
//insert into customer_quote table
$database->query("INSERT INTO customer_quote (cid) Values ('$customer->cid')");
```

BTW, nice post with images, etc...

Comment: Thanks, but now I get this error: -'Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`quote_system`.`customer_quote`, CONSTRAINT `fk_customer_quote_customer` FOREIGN KEY (`cid`) REFERENCES `customer` (`id`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION)' i

Comment: Well it says that the ID is not valid based on the customer table. Probably same thing will happen with your user's table cause you instert a NULL in a non-null table.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing a parenthese:

```
"INSERT INTO customer_quote (cid) Values ('$customer->cid')"
```